# using AccountManager addAccountExplicitly takes a long time for the first sync

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, accountmanager, android-syncadapter

I use AccountManager addAccountExplicitly() to add an account to AccountManager.
I then call

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, true);
```

After doing that, when looking in the device's "Accounts & sync" screen, i see my account BUT when I click on in, I see that the "Sync contacts" check box does not appear.
It may take a few minutes for it to appear...

I found out that if I listen to the account being added, and after a delay (2 secs) call:

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, new Bundle());
```

It is being synced.

1.why does it take time for the account to sync?
2.is this the correct way to make the account sync immediately? (will this always work?)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the edited part in this answer helped me. [First time sync loops indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191838/first-time-sync-loops-indefinitely)

On the first sync, call `cancelSync` and try sync again.

> `ContentResolver.cancelSync(account, authority);`