# infinite sync loop syncadapter

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have the same problem stated here: [Android SyncAdapter stuck in infinite sync loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080476/android-syncadapter-stuck-in-infinite-sync-loop)

But after trying to implement the notifychange (Uri uri, ContentObserver observer, boolean syncToNetwork) in onPerformSync, I realized that I didn't know how to get the ContentObserver that I needed (which is defined and passed in in the main activity)

Any tips?

EDIT 1:

like this person [First time sync loops indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191838/first-time-sync-loops-indefinitely)

I found that ContentResolver.cancelSync(account, authority); will work as well, but if anyone has a better solution...please let me know!

EDIT 2:

I followed the advice from this post [Android SyncAdapter Automatically Initialize Syncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090604/android-syncadapter-automatically-initialize-syncing)

after stepping through with the debugger, I confirmed that SyncToNetwork is most definitely false when it is passed into notifyChange, yet the infinite sync continues without the cancelSync...still no permanent solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question some time ago when I was just dipping my toes into Android programming, and I figured I'd share what I found for anyone who's curious. When I was following tutorials to implement a custom ContentProvider, I saw that `notifyChange (Uri uri, ContentObserver observer)` was used after the `update()`, `insert()` and `delete()` methods. Not really knowing anything, I also called `notifyChange` in my ContentProvider. This led to problems like infinite sync loops that I just could not figure out. There is an overloaded method: `notifyChange (Uri uri, ContentObserver observer, boolean syncToNetwork)` which I knew about then, but I could never figure out how to use it because my `notifyChange` was being called in my ContentProvider. This was actually an easy fix. All I had to do was call `notifyChange (uri, null, false)` not in my ContentProvider, but rather, after calling those methods through the ContentResolver `getContentResolver().insert()` etc.

I hope this helps someone.